# Elasticsearch: Simple name search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement a simple name search using elasticsearch and a java app as the client.

**Schema:**

```
{
    "firstname": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "standard"
    },
    "lastname": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "standard"
    },
    "fullname": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "standard"
    }
}
```

**Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "fullname": {
              "query": "Michael Jordan",
              "type": "boolean",
              "fuzziness": 1,
              "minimum_should_match": "100%"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "lastname": {
              "query": "Michael Jordan",
              "type": "boolean",
              "fuzziness": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Code:**

```
String fullname = QueryParser.escape(queryFullname);
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = boolQuery()
  .must(matchQuery("fullname", fullname).fuzziness(fuzziness).minimumShouldMatch("100%")) 
  .must(matchQuery("lastname", fullname).fuzziness(fuzziness));
```

**Requirements:**

- Use the existing mapping. This means that I can't change the analyzer. This doesn't affect a lot, as the only thing I would add is asciifolding.
- Return results when searching only with lastname, but do not when searching only with firstname
- Allow space for errors in the query param. This is the reason for the fuzziness, it also takes care the absence of asciifolding, although it narrows the window error.

**Explanation:**

- I'm using `must` in fullname and lastname only, since searching with firstname would break one of the requirements.
- I'm using minimum should match of 100% in fullname since I want all query terms to have a match with the document terms in order to mark it as a result. There is a window of error through fuzziness.
- The reason I'm using fullname too, and not only last name is because I want to get better scores when the whole fullname is a match.
- The reason I'm using the lastname can be better explained through an example

**Documents:**

- fullname: Paul Foo Bar, firstname: Paul, lastname: Foo Bar
- fullname: Paul Alkis Desk, firstname: Paul, lastname: Alkis Desk

**Query:**

- Paul Bar

The query as is, will bring Paul Foo Bar which I want.
If I use only the fullname and remove minimum should match it will bring both (because of Paul) which I don't want. If I keep and play with minimum should match the results will become very inconsistent.

My question is, is the logic good enough? Is there a better (i.e. faster or more reliable) way to do what I need without changing the mapping? I haven't tested the performance yet, but can you spot any major performance pitfalls?

I'm using `ElasticSearch 1.7.5`

p.s. If you find this to be utterly wrong and for a variety of reasons, then feel free to say so and point me to some useful reading material. I'm a new to elasticsearch.